# Protocol restriction on another protocol associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I have a protocol `MyProtocol` which has an `associatedtype`, inferred by the return type of `myFunction`

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var myVar: Int
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func myFunction()-> MyType
}

class MyClass1: MyProtocol {
    func myFunction()-> MyStruct? {
        return MyStruct(myVar: 1) //ex.
    }
}

class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    func myFunction()-> Int? {
        return 1 // ex.
    }
}
```

- In `MyClass1`, `associatedtype` is infered as `MyStruct?`
- In `MyClass2`, `associatedtype` is infered as `Int?`

from there everything works fine. No I want to build another protocol that can only be applied to a **MyProtocol if associatedtype is Codable** :

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType == Codable? {}
```

the code runs fine until here but when I try to apply it to my class I get an error:

```
extension MyClass1: MyProtocolCodable{}
```

> 'MyProtocolCodable' requires the types 'MyStruct?' and 'Codable?' (aka 'Optional<Decodable & Encodable>') be equivalent

yet, as far as I can see `MyStruct?` (aka Optional) and `Codable?` (aka Optional<Decodable & Encodable>) are equivalent?

How can I get rid of this error message? Am I doing something that is not meant to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can see MyStruct? (aka Optional) and Codable? (aka
> Optional<Decodable & Encodable>) are equivalent?

No, they are not. `MyStruct` *conforms* to `Codable` but is not *equivalent* of it.

As in: *every MyStruct is Codable but not every Codable is MyStruct*.

---

You can try changing `MyType == Codable?` to `MyType: Codable`:

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: Codable {}
```

as `MyStruct` is not equal to `Codable?`.

Comment: Thanks this works fine for the error described! However I may have simplified the problem while passing it into the playground to make it simplier for SO... I get another message that I thaught was a side effect of the first one while debugging it. I am trying to conform to an Array of Codable and not just Codable itself. If you have any idea? I edited my question accordingly

Comment: @Olympiloutre It does look like a different question though. Your original one didn't mention it and it changes the whole context. I'd suggest you remove your edit from this question and post it as a new one.

Comment: understood Ill do that. Thanks